# How do we handle NDAs for Teams?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-for-teams

Since Teams doesn't allow self-hosting (we are not planning to become an "enterprise" customer) how do we ensure a non-disclosure agreement (NDA) with Stack Overflow, considering that our content will be hosted remotely by them?

I cannot simply just sign up for a 14-day trial, as that will end up charging me.

Comment: How do NDAs work for any remote hosted information? Can you send mail through G-mail that contains NDA'd information? I'm not sure what this has to do with SO Teams specifically.

Comment: @NicolBolas I interpreted it as asking if SO is willing to actually put something in writing indicating that the content for a given team (or all teams?) is private and won't be released, or something like that.

Comment: @NicolBolas - No mention of it - how do I handle it without SO signing an NDA not to disclose our information?  The site just says sign up for a 14 day trial.  How do I handle ensuring NDA compliance?  If you send NDA information over gmail you broke the promise...

Comment: @JonH: Then you have your answer, don't you? If you cannot use off-site hosted services for your NDA'd content in general, why would SO Teams be any different in this regard? SO Teams is clearly "private", just like your G-mail account. But if that isn't good enough to use G-mail, then it probably won't be good enough for Teams.

Comment: @NicolBolas - Not cannot use - just would like NDA signed.

Comment: @JonH I'm not sure what your last sentence has to do with your question. It also doesn't sound accurate; you can cancel the trial at any time without being charged AFAIK

Answer (score 54):

There are confidentiality/NDA provisions in the Terms of Service for Stack Overflow for Teams (specifically Sections [4](https://stackexchange.com/legal/terms-of-service/private#permissions) and [9](https://stackexchange.com/legal/terms-of-service/private#confidential)).

So yes, we are absolutely contractually obligated not to just randomly show your private information to other people :-).

Also very few people here even have the ability to access the data inside a Teams instance (only a few members of the SRE and Architecture teams), and even then are restricted only to doing so after receiving explicit written permission from the admin of a Team.  Full details there are on the [Teams Security Overview](https://stackoverflow.help/en/articles/4387775-security-overview).